# What are the problems with a gamma radiation-pair production reactor?

Tags: particle-physics, gamma-rays

I'm sure that physicits already thought about it but what are the potential problems to make an energy reactor that works like this :

1. we send an initial gamma ray on some matter in a closed environment
2. some electron-positron pairs will be created
3. each pair will annihilate to give two gamma photons
4. so for each gamma photon, we get two, which will collide with the sample
5. the process repeats, we got our chain reaction and we harvest this energy

I know there is a problem that the gamma photos can't be stopped from escaping, can we force them to circulate in a torus?

Thanks

Comment: At step 3, the two gamma rays generated do not have enough energy to each produce pair production. End of 'reaction', end of story.

Comment: This process has a name. It's called "an electromagnetic cascade" or "an electromagnetic shower". And it doesn't generate energy: it's just redistributes the energy that was in the original photon. And collecting it involves inevitable losses.

Comment: @JonCuster If the original photon is energetic enough the early generation leptons can be highly boosted allowing a number of generations before the process dies away.

Comment: @dmckee - sure, but die away it will. The conceptual problem seems to be getting two gammas for the price of one over and over and over again.

Comment: @JonCuster thank you very much for your help, I understand now, the generated electron-positron and the gamma rays will not take any energy from the associated atoms, the energy of the original photons will be divided in the chain reaction until the energy became too weak and the chain reaction stops

Comment: @dmckee thank you very much for your help, I understand now, the generated electron-positron and the gamma rays will not take any energy from the associated atoms, the energy of the original photons will be divided in the chain reaction until the energy became too weak and the chain reaction stops